# How to take user input 'XXX' to end?

Tags: python, list, stack, user-input

```py
stack.append('a')
stack.append('b')
stack.append('c')
stack.append('d')
```

What should I do to take input like this?

- Enter element, 'XXX' to end: a
- Enter element, 'XXX' to end: b
- Enter element, 'XXX' to end: c
- Enter element, 'XXX' to end: XXX

Comment: Initial stack
['a', 'b', 'c']

Elements popped from stack:
c
b
a

Stack after elements are popped:
[]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? Explain the question as much as you can.

Comment: @cemodvvdgre: Welcome to stackoverflow. You might want to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your requestion accordingly. I for myself would like to help, but have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to take user input and append it to a stack.

You can use `list` for this as mentioned below:

```
stack = []
elem = input("Enter element, 'XXX' to end:")

while elem != 'XXX':
    stack.append(elem)
    elem = input("Enter element, 'XXX' to end:")
```

Alternatively, you can also use `collections.deque` which is more efficient than `list`.

```
from collections import deque

stack = deque()
elem = input("Enter element, 'XXX' to end:")

while elem != 'XXX':
    stack.append(elem)
    elem = input("Enter element, 'XXX' to end:")
```

To pop elements, simply use `stack.pop()` which would remove the last inserted element from `list` or `deque`.